# How to use JDBC Connection Pool in Restlet Java Webservice?

Tags: java, rest, connection-pooling, restlet

Hi All I am using REST framework to devlope webservice in Java through **restlet API**.
I am using Tomcat 6.0.35 as web container.

I want to use **Database Connection Pool** for JDBC connection in my project.
I came to know about **BoneCP** is good one, so I want to try it.

I have 20 webservices in one project i.e. one Resource class for one webservice. And there is single Application class that routes each web service by clients request.

Right now I am opening and closing the JDBC Connection in every webservice.

So my question is, **How can I use one JDBC connection for all webservices?**
In which class I have to open and close the JDBC connection?

Please help me.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I would suggest you use Hibernate with C3P0 connection pooling , its best , it directly gives you sessions and you dont have to worry about closing the connection etc.

Comment: Thanks Mohan for quick reply. But I dont know a little about Hibernate.

Comment: Ok ! Then try implementing Connection Factory pattern , its easy to implement with JDBC ,

this link would help:

http://javateacher.co.in/core-java/jdbc/jdbc-dao-example-2/

Comment: Thanks Mohan, it is very nice tutorial.